# Create Excel function to get yahoo finance stock quote

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, yahoo-finance

I have come across the following VBA code which works perfectly for me to create a function in Excel that gets the Yahoo Finance stock quote of a ticker in a certain cell.

The only shortcoming of the code is that it gets me the last quote, whereas I would also like to have a similar function for the stock value e.g. 7 days ago, 1 months and 6 months ago. (i.e. =today()-7 days or =today()-30 days.

Is there a way to modify it so i can create the required new functions e.g. StockPrice1week , StockPrice6M etc.

I do not need the 1 week or 6 month range rather just the single closing value on that date.
I am not looking for any other macros or alternatives, but just a modification of this VBA vode.

```
Function StockQuote(ticker As String)
    ' Get near real-time stock quote from Yahoo via JSON query

    Dim URL As String, response As String, stripped As String, inbits() As String, i As Long
    Dim request As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest                               ' needs Tools|References|WinHTTP Services
    On Error GoTo Err

    URL = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=" & Trim(ticker)
    Set request = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    With request
        .Open "GET", URL, True
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .Send
        .WaitForResponse
        response = .responseText
    End With

    If InStr(response, """result"":[]") <> 0 Then GoTo Err              ' ticker not found

    'kludge parse: strip JSON delimiters and quotes
    stripped = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(response, "[", ""), "]", ""), "{", ""), "}", ""), """", "")

    stripped = Replace(stripped, ":", ":,")                             ' keep colons for readability, but make them delimit
    inbits = split(stripped, ",")                                       ' split

    i = LBound(inbits)
    Do While inbits(i) <> "regularMarketPrice:" And i <= UBound(inbits) ' find "regularMarketPrice:" tag
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    If i > UBound(inbits) Or Not IsNumeric(inbits(i + 1)) Then          ' not found; look for previous close
        i = LBound(inbits)
        Do While inbits(i) <> "regularMarketPreviousClose:" _
                                            And i <= UBound(inbits)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        If i > UBound(inbits) Or Not IsNumeric(inbits(i + 1)) Then GoTo Err
    End If

    StockQuote = Val(inbits(i + 1))                                     ' price is next element
    Exit Function

Err:
    StockQuote = CVErr(xlErrNA)

End Function
```

I believe ti would be something to do with this snippet in particular, but am not 100% sure?!

```
Do While inbits(i) <> "regularMarketPrice:" And i <= UBound(inbits) ' find "regularMarketPrice:" tag
    i = i + 1
Loop

If i > UBound(inbits) Or Not IsNumeric(inbits(i + 1)) Then          ' not found; look for previous close
    i = LBound(inbits)
    Do While inbits(i) <> "regularMarketPreviousClose:" _
                                        And i <= UBound(inbits)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    If i > UBound(inbits) Or Not IsNumeric(inbits(i + 1)) Then GoTo Err
End If
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: just add range `range` parameter to your url. e.g for Apple last six months --> https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=aapl&range=6MO

Comment: this does not work. I am looking for a single value on that date (1 week ago, or 6 months ago) to be displayed in one cell and not the whole range it has traded over the past 6 months.

Comment: It would help if you provided a sample ticker and expected values for the different time periods.

Comment: We can take AAPL for example. I would like to get the value of the stock on "today()-7 days" and "today()-30 days"  i.e. 23 Nov 2018 and 30 Oct 2018, where today is obviously going to vary.